# 3 week old Lawn growing very patchy (Need Help)

Tags: lawn, grass, germination

I recently moved into a new house and the garden was horrible and basically had no grass, so I dug it all upturned the soil and removed all stones and weeks, really the soil looked great quality. I then proceeded to put some new grass seed down, that was 3 weeks ago, the is growing well and is now about 3-4 inches long but some areas are basically bald with no sign of life I would estimate 30% of the lawn is like this. Should I reseed it or?